# Wireshark not opening in x11 terminal

Tags: bash, wireshark, xterm

Hello i am using MAC Mavericks system.i have installed wireshark .dmg and x11 .dmg(xquartz) .But when i try to open  wireshark in Xterm  ,using the command

```
bash-3.2$ open/Applications/Wireshark.app/
```

i get the following error message.

```
bash: open/Applications/Wireshark.app/: No such file or directory.
```

Actually i can see a blue icon called wireshark in my applications folder,but i get the above error  message instead of the wireshark program.
Am i missing something?Please give some suggestions on installation of Wireshark on MAC Mavericks?

I am a newbie in wireshark.please help me .

Comment: put a space after `open`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dagg Nabbit said, place a space after `open`; the command to open a file from the command line is

```
open {file}
```

so, to open `/Applications/Wireshark.app`, do

```
open /Applications/Wireshark.app
```

Comment: can you suggest some article to learn Wireshark?